# What's the css for a transparent border?

Tags: html, css, web, transparency

I have a 'special' table on one page, that's borders I would like invisible. I'd like it to differ from standard css rules. Here is a screenshot:

[before http://eliteshift.com/redbeancoffee/images/before.jpg](http://eliteshift.com/redbeancoffee/images/before.jpg)

And here is what I want:

[after http://eliteshift.com/redbeancoffee/images/after.jpg](http://eliteshift.com/redbeancoffee/images/after.jpg)

I've made a second 'class' called 'award', and I can attribute certain traits (such as width), but I cannot for the life of me remove the boarder.

What's the css for a transparent border?

I've tried:

```
table.award {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    width:60%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-color: transparent;` will make it transparent.

`border:none;` will remove the border, which sounds like what you actually want in this case.

Answer (score 1):

From the sounds of it, do you actually need a border? Would the following work?

```
table.award{
    border: none;
    /*other css attributes omited*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that `border: 2px solid transparent` doesn't make it truly transparent all the time.

To make sure that you have a transparent border with a fixed width, use margins instead:

```
margin: 2px
```

will do the trick